# PHP/MYSQL Security Questions (Online Order Form, Admin Portal)

Tags: php, mysql, html, security

I'm writing a dynamic site that is powered by PHP and MySQL (to be run on a WAMP server). My current concerns are about the security of the site, and I have a few questions. I had a thread about it yesterday, and got tons of help! Thanks so much to everyone so far! However, SO blocked me from editing that post for some reason, so I had to make a new one...

1) I am writing an admin portal for the site so that the owners of it can manipulate the MySQL database in an easy, user-friendly way on the website (from a login HTML page using HTTPS). Every page within the portal will use HTTPS as well. My concern for security here is the login process, which consists of the login page and a PHP login script, and then the authentication of the session on pages within the actual portal after logging in. First, gathering the user login information:

```
<form method="post" action="admin/login.php">
<table align="center">
<tr><th>Admin Login Form</th></tr>
<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="Name" size="30" onKeyPress="return aJSFunctionToStopEnterKeyFromWorking(event)"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="Password" size="30" onKeyPress="return aJSFunctionToStopEnterKeyFromWorking(event)"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="reset" value="Clear Form"> <input type="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Second, the actual login script:

```
<?php
$inputusername = $_POST['Name'];
$inputpassword = $_POST['Password'];

$username = "a username that is not obvious";
$password = "a password that is at least 10 characters long";

if($username == $inputusername && $password == $inputpassword) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['valid'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['IP'] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $_SESSION['agent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    header('Location: portal.php');
    exit;
}
else {echo  "<center>Invalid username or password<br><a href='../admin.html'>Try Again</a></center>"; exit;}
?>
```

And then after the login process, each page of the portal will have the following script included at the beginning of the file:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['valid']) {header('Location: ../admin.html'); exit;}
if($_SESSION['IP'] != $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) {header('Location: ../admin.html'); exit;}
if($_SESSION['agent'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) {header('Location: ../admin.html'); exit;}
?>
```

So then each portal page will be something like the following:

```
<?php include('session-authentication-script.php'); ?>
*Actual page goes here*
```

I also made the logout script:

```
<?php
include('session-authentication-script.php');
$_SESSION['valid'] = FALSE;
session_destroy();
header('Location: ../admin.html');
exit;
?>
```

So does all of this look relatively safe now? Or do I still have gaping holes in my security...

2) Someone mentioned I am still susceptible to XSS, however I don't see how. Could someone explain to me what this means:

> as simple as echo "Requested article: ".$_GET['id']' thing is already vulnerable.

I tried googling to figure out what this meant, but I couldn't find anything related to security. I would really appreciate if anyone could explain this to me! The user who commented this did it without any real context, so I am not even really sure what it applies to (my last thread also covered SQL injection attacks... if you want more context, here is the link to the old thread: [Dynamic Website Security Questions (PHP+MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651761/dynamic-website-security-questions-phpmysql/5651996#5651996)).

3) I also have some scripts that will be emailing sensitive data (credit card numbers) from user input HTML forms. How do I ensure that this data is properly protected? Both the forms and scripts will be set to use HTTPS. Here is basically a short example of how it works:

```
<form name="Order" method="post" action="incl/email_Order.php">
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="Name" size="30" onKeyPress="return aJSFunctionToStopEnterKeyFromWorking(event)" ></td></tr>

*gather up a bunch more form data in the same fashion*

<tr><td></td><td><input type="reset" value="Clear Form"> <input type="submit" value="Submit Order" ></td></tr></table>
```

Then, here is the email script:

```
$to = "sales@company.com";
$subject = "Online Order";
$message = "Name: " . $_REQUEST['Name'] . "\r\n" .

*and here is a bunch of other stuff being concatenated to $message in the same fashion*

$headers = 'From: sales@company.com' . "\r\n" .
       'Reply-To: ' . $_REQUEST['Email'] . "\r\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {print "Thank you for your order!";}
else {print "We encountered an error sending your order. Please attempt again.";}
exit;
```

So is HTTPS enough to keep this secure? Are there are flaws here that leave it open?

4) Any other security concerns I should know/think about?

I really appreciate any more help I get with this!

Comment: If you want to use a database, you'd better use parameter binding for sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 3):

2)

```
echo "Requested article: ".$_GET['id'];
```

What if someone supplies

```
'<script src="bad_script_from_bad_server.js"></script>'
```

as id?

You need to validate $_GET['id'] before you use it.

One way could be the use of filter_input()

Assuming id is expected as integer:

```
echo "Requested article: ".filter_input ( INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

Comment: assuming id is an integer you could as well use a simplier cast "Requested article: ". (int) $_GET['id'] . But you're right to notice the 'filter_input' way as it's the generdi way of thinking.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for your crystal clear explanation of this. I get it now, awesome. I will have to go through a lot of places on the site where I do $_GET and $_REQUEST calls and make sure I protect against this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Login - in your example, you are not authenticating anything against the db, you're comparing two values of a variable. There's no mechanism that prevents anyone to create a script that will try to brute-force your login script, meaning repeatedly enter values until it finds the proper one.
   Usually, people allow for certain number of logins from a single IP address in order to stop script kiddies from trying to brute force the admin login.
2. Yes, if you do echo "Article with ID ". $_GET['id'] ." not found" - nothing prevents an attacker to inject a JS from his site into your computer and gain control over the website in a certain way. It is speculative, however someone might be logged in into your website (say, you) and if the attacker provides you with a link such as "/admin.php?id=" - you're going to load HIS javascript, which means he can do malicious things with YOUR session - such as hijacking your session among other things and get the actual administration access from which he can delete your data. 
   It is one of those "catastrophic" things that can occur, but they have happened before and are happening today - if you can avoid it, do so. Always clean the input - sticking intval($_GET['id']) doesn't hurt, and makes the variable you receive of the proper type.
3. Emailing credit card details - that's a big no. Dealing with highly confidential information such as credit cards has to be approached in a different way - usually, if you interact with 3rd party software (some sort of payment gateway), you establish an encrypted connection first before exchanging the data. Also, sending credit card info via email means that someone with sufficient privileges at target machine can read that email. You have no guarantee that the target person (or service) read that email and no one else if you use email in such a way that you are doing.
   On the other hand, NO ONE should be aware of someone's credit card details except some sort of a service that debits or credits the account - meaning no living person should have access to those details except the credit card owner. All of the payment gateways work in such a way. Also, if you attempt to store credit card information for recurring billing or something similar - I assume you know that the user first has to agree to that and that you have to encrypt the data you're saving.
4. There are many things when it comes to security of online apps, especially the ones created with PHP. Is your website at shared hosting plan? If yes, where are the sessions stored? Are they stored in /tmp folder? If yes, that means you can create a script that reads all the files saved in /tmp and basically obtain other websites' data. Same way, you can modify existing sessions which renders your security plan for logging users in in clause 1) void. And this is just one thing that pops to my mind, imagine what would a determined cracker do if he/she wanted to take your site down.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help! I'm going to be checking failed login attempts per IP address and ban IPs that fail too many times. The server is going to be dedicated, not shared, so hopefully that should be safe... as long as our hosting company is secure, it should be, right?

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS (tries to) guarantees three things:

- that the site your user's visiting is genuinely you, and that a reliable third party (the certificate issuer) trusts you (i.e. no phishing)
- that the data is secure between leaving your client and getting to your secure server
- that the data that leaves your client is the same as the data that gets to your server.

Any more you have to set up yourself. For example, the password in your code is only as secure as the server; if somebody can see that source code they'll have the password.

More secure options could be...

- password in a database, so it can be changed easily; secure the database, set constraints so the password has to be complex enough.
- checks that the user is unlikely to be a bot (captcha)
- checks for fast repeated attempts to login from one machine, a possible sign of a brute force attack
- if the password is the same for all site users (which is what you code does), making sure your users are aware of the risks. Individual logins are safer.
- if you do use a password database, protect it against SQL injection (http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: How can they see that source code, other than getting onto the server though? And once they have access to the code on the server, isn't there a lot more they can do than simply take the admin portal password? I mean, the MySQL login information is also stored on the server in a PHP script somewhere so that the site can use the MySQL DB, so I don't see how it is any better to have the password in the DB... sorry if I am confused, I just wanted to understand more :)

Answer (score 0):

Strip input field from using tags before input in database:

```
$inputUserName = strip_tags(trim($_POST["Name"]));
```